# What is the best way for other ViewModel to get a reference to NavigationModel according to WWDC example?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10054 it is shown that the best way to organize an iPad layout is by:

```
struct TwoColumnContentView: View {
    @Binding var showExperiencePicker: Bool
    @EnvironmentObject private var navigationModel: NavigationModel
    var categories = Category.allCases
    var dataModel = DataModel.shared

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(
            columnVisibility: $navigationModel.columnVisibility
        ) {
            List(
                categories,
                selection: $navigationModel.selectedCategory
            ) { category in
                NavigationLink(category.localizedName, value: category)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Categories")
            .toolbar {
                ExperienceButton(isActive: $showExperiencePicker)
            }
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack(path: $navigationModel.recipePath) {
                RecipeGrid(category: navigationModel.selectedCategory)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NavigationModel defined as

```
final class NavigationModel: ObservableObject, Codable {
    @Published var selectedCategory: Category?
    @Published var recipePath: [Recipe]
    @Published var columnVisibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility
}
```

But what happens when in a child view, it triggers off some action in some other ViewModel that needs to update the navigation stack?

```
struct ChildViewModel {
   func childViewCalledAndDidSomething {
      //now I need to update recipePath, how?
   }
}
```

Comment: “Best” is subjective. You could pass a callback function to the child view model as one example.

Comment: You can create your own wrapper

Comment: In SwiftUI the View struct is the view model already, you don't need another one

Comment: @malhal this sample code is from Apple's best practices recommendations from last year.

Comment: Yeh but the sample project that was taken from didn't even work. My guess is it was written by some junior dev not fully experienced with SwiftUI.